# Code only printing 0 when calculating the sum of two given odd numbers

Tags: java, loops, input, sum

Okay So I've written out the code with what I believe is correct, but it always outputs a 0. Here is what I have:

```
    System.out.println("Enter a range of 2 numbers: ");
    int a;
    int b;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    a = in.nextInt();
    b = in.nextInt();
    int z = 0;
    int sum4 = 0;
    while (z >= a && z >=b)
    {
        if(x % 2 != 0)
        {
            sum4 += x;
        }
        x++;
    }
    System.out.println(sum4);
```

Comment: `z >= a && z >=b` will never be true if `a` or `b` is more than 0. And I don't see `x` defined at all.

Comment: ... because you're setting `z=0`

Comment: It is **impossible** for that code to print a `0`, because it *doesn't compile*. What is `x`?

Comment: Okay I feel like an idiot. The x was supposed to be a z.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to add all odd numbers between a and b, in which case using a for loop would be a much better option setting the initial value to be a and the final value to be b.